# How can you identify what versions of VS Code an extensions will work with?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install the MS Python extension (ms-python.python-2020.7.96456.vsix) on a VS Code (1.40.2) install and I'm receiving the following error. "Unable to install extension 'ms-python-python' as it is not compatible with VS Code '1.40.2'". How do I go about finding out what version would be compatible? I'm in an environment where I can't connect to the internet, so the vsix must be used in an offline mode.

Comment: You probably have to update VSCode. The current version is 1.50.1

Comment: open the vsix file with an zip tool and look in the package.json file for the minimal needed version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks rioV8! After looking into the package.json I've found that the "engines" field is what details the minimum version of VS Code required.

Per code.visualstudio.com (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension)

> Visual Studio Code compatibility
>
> When authoring an extension, you will need to describe what is the
> extension's compatibility to Visual Studio Code itself. This can be
> done via the engines.vscode field inside package.json:
>
> {   "engines": {
> "vscode": "^1.8.0"   } }
>
> A value of 1.8.0 means that your extension is compatible only with VS
> Code 1.8.0. A value of ^1.8.0 means that your extension is compatible
> with VS Code 1.8.0 and onwards, including 1.8.1, 1.9.0, etc.
>
> You can use the engines.vscode field to make sure the extension only
> gets installed for clients that contain the API you depend on. This
> mechanism plays well with the Stable release as well as the Insiders
> one.
>
> For example, imagine that the latest Stable version of VS Code is
> 1.8.0 and that during 1.9.0's development a new API is introduced and thus made available in the Insider release through version
> 1.9.0-insider. If you want to publish an extension version that benefits from this API, you should indicate a version dependency of
> ^1.9.0. Your new extension version will be installed only on VS Code
> greater than or equal to 1.9.0, which means all current Insider customers will get it, while the Stable ones will only get the update when Stable reaches 1.9.0.